# trytond 3.8 xml parsin error

Tags: python, xml, tryton

I get errors when trying to install module timesheets by 
command `sudo trytond -c t.conf -v -d trytond -u timesheet_cost ir`

I get error:

```
ERROR trytond.convert Error while parsing xml file:
In tag record: model ir.property with id property_party_sequence.
```

It uses Sax parser in python but can fix the xml? Or is there any fixes for python sax parser?

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: Yes. Issues was with the MySQL. I tried to use MySQL with trytond, so I changed to PostgresSQL. Then it worked well.